# Trying to create Person Account via marketing cloud using CreateSalesforceObject in Ampscript

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud

hoping someone can help.

My code ie below is trying to create a Person Account in Salesforce via a cloud page in marketing cloud. I keep getting an error.

````
if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then

  var @createAccount, @RecordTypeId
  set @RecordTypeId = "0121r000000q5UqAAI"
  set @createAccount = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Account", 4,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "PersonEmail", RequestParameter("email"),
        "RecordTypeId", @RecordTypeId
       )

endif

]%%
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      %%[ if not empty(@createAccount) then ]%%
         <p>%%=v(@createAccount)=%% record created in Account Object</p>
      %%[ endif ]%%
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <label>Last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <label>Year of Entry</label>
         <input type="text" name="Yearofentry">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="email">
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>```

I am getting an error 
***500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.***

Any ideas?  

(Note: I got this working for leads but when it comes to Person Accounts and trying to reference a RecordTypeid, i think i am missing something)
````

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I managed to solve this. I removed the below and it seemed to work - still unsure why this was preventing it from working but removing it did the trick.

Year of Entry